# Group ID based on individual rank

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier

I have the following individual data and I want to make an unique household identifier. Every individual already has its rank in household so basically rank 1 marks the start of the new household. 
e.g.

```
rank name
1    John
2    Lisa
3    Stu
1    Phil
1    Mike
1    Florence
2    George
3    David
4    Diana
1    Eleanor
```

The result I am looking for is this:

```
rank name      id
1    John      1
2    Lisa      1
3    Stu       1
1    Phil      2
1    Mike      3
1    Florence  4
2    George    4
3    David     4
4    Diana     4
1    Eleanor   5
```

There are around 320 000 individuals, so group id should go from 1 to sum(df$rank[rank = 1]) or something similar. Any other type of unique ID also works, it doesn't have to be seq(1,n,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$rank == 1)

#    rank     name id
# 1     1     John  1
# 2     2     Lisa  1
# 3     3      Stu  1
# 4     1     Phil  2
# 5     1     Mike  3
# 6     1 Florence  4
# 7     2   George  4
# 8     3    David  4
# 9     4    Diana  4
# 10    1  Eleanor  5
```

As @Andre Elrico noted, if `rank` is `NA` for any rows, the method above would give you `NA` for `id` in all subsequent rows, so you could use the option below instead if you know `rank` may be `NA` (but not when it should be 1).

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$rank %in% 1)
```

Data used:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
rank name
1    John
2    Lisa
3    Stu
1    Phil
1    Mike
1    Florence
2    George
3    David
4    Diana
1    Eleanor
', header = T)
```

Comment: `cumsum(df$rank %in% 1)` in case of `NA` ranks

Comment: Good point. Although if there are `NA`s I would worry about having a `NA` where a 1 should be, which would mess up the `id`s anyway

Comment: sure, I just benchmarked it. `%in%` is muuuuch slower than `==`. Just wanted to throw that in case your solution would fail on OP.